# Import Oracle table dump with insert statements and clob data types using Java

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, dump, clob

I have an Oracle table dump containing insert statements. Some of the tables contain clob data fields. If I try to restore the dump using SQL Developer I get the error "ORA-01704: string literal too long"

Now I tried to restore the dump with JDBC using Java. The problem is that I already have the fully composed PreparedStatement so I cannot change the datatype of the columns from string to clob.

In the following the application is listed:

```
// strBufLine contains already the fully composed insert statement from the dump file
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("BEGIN " + strBufLine.toString() + " END;");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pstmt.close();
```

Any idea how to solve this issue (using another program to restore the dump, other dump technique or how to change the datatype to clob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string literal is too long for SQL Developer, it will be too long for JDBC as well because it's parsed on the server side.

I propose you convert the file into a CSV or fixed length file. That shouldn't be too difficult since it's the dump of a single table. So each line will have a similar structure. It might even be possible to do it in a text editor with Search/Replace.

Then you can import it using SQL Developer (*Import Data...* in the context menu on the desired table).

Comment: I tried to export the table as .csv file and tried to import it. Again I got the same error message ...

Comment: Indeed, SQL Developer seems to be as stupid as it gets when importing CLOB data. Toad is said to be better at it though I couldn't verify it. Another approach is to use a Java CSV parser and JDBC.

Comment: I parsed the data now with a Java CSV parser and the following statements:
    Clob clob = connection.createClob();
    clob.setString(1, "CLOB String");
    pstmt.setClob(1, clob);